# (I think) Thrift server is only listening on ipv6

Tags: delphi, thrift

I am new to Apache Thrift and was playing around with the toy Delphi client server example that Apache provides here: https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/delphi

We've made some minor changes to names and to how the port and IP is set up, but basically identical otherwise.

In the **server** we have the following code:

```
    PORT := StrToInt(ParamStr(1));
    handler   := TPhraseGeneratorHandler.Create;
    processor := TPhraseGenerator.TProcessorImpl.Create( handler);
    transport := TServerSocketImpl.Create( PORT);
    server    := TSimpleServer.Create( processor, transport);

    WriteLn( 'Starting the server on port ' + PORT.ToString + '...');
    server.Serve();
```

In the **client** we have the following code:

```
var transport     : ITransport;
    protocol      : IProtocol;
    client        : TPhraseGenerator.Iface;
    phraseRequest : IPhraseRequest;
// Let the user pass in the parameters for host and port
    HOST : String;
    PORT : Integer;

begin
  try
    // Open a connection to the server using the host and port supplied by the user
    HOST := ParamStr(1);
    PORT := StrToInt(ParamStr(2));
    WriteLn('Openning a connection to the server: ' + HOST + ' on port: ' + PORT.ToString);
    transport := TSocketImpl.Create( HOST, PORT, 10000); // specifically add a timeout as our test server deliberately goes to sleep for 5000ms
    protocol  := TBinaryProtocolImpl.Create( transport);
    client    := TPhraseGenerator.TClient.Create( protocol);
    transport.Open;
```

If we open the client and server on the same machine and use 'localhost' we can get them to communicate.

If however we open them on different machines and specify the server's ipv4 address we cannot.

Using netstat we get the following:

```
D:\Temp>netstat -ano | findstr 9090
  TCP    [::]:9090              [::]:0                 LISTENING       15368
```

Which I think indicates that the server is only listening on ipv6.

Q: Am i correct? and if so how can we get it to listen on ipv4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that [you are 100% correct](https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=lib/delphi/src/Thrift.Socket.pas;h=b33f20276c23b00d130c3a29bcc42c90dc261c19;hb=HEAD#l589).

The relevant section from `CreateSocket()`:

```
// Pick the ipv6 address first since ipv4 addresses can be mapped
// into ipv6 space.
Res := Result.Res;
while Assigned(Res) do begin
    if (Res^.ai_family = AF_INET6) or (not Assigned(Res^.ai_next)) then
        Break;
    Res := Res^.ai_next;
end;

FSocket := Winapi.Winsock2.socket(Res^.ai_family, Res^.ai_socktype, Res^.ai_protocol);
```

Comment: In case you're interested @JensG, an upgdate below

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
We have figured out how to edit the Delphi Thrift code to allow ipv4.  Posting here in case it helps anyone else.

The relevant pocedure is *procedure TServerSocket.Listen;* in file *Thrift.Sockets.pas*.

```
procedure TServerSocket.Listen;
```

:

```
var
  TempIntReader,
  TempIntWriter: Winapi.Winsock2.TSocket;
  One: Cardinal;
  ErrnoCopy: Integer;
  Ling: TLinger;
  Retries: Integer;
  AddrInfo: IGetAddrInfoWrapper;
  SA: TSockAddrStorage;
  Len: Integer;

  // ### ADD THIS ###
  Zero: Cardinal;
  // ### END ADD ###
```

:

```
// Set SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE to prevent 2MSL delay on accept
  One := 1;
  setsockopt(Socket, SOL_SOCKET, Integer(SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE), @one, SizeOf(One));
  // ignore errors coming out of this setsockopt on Windows.  This is because
  // SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE requires admin privileges on WinXP, but we don't
  // want to force servers to be an admin.

  // ### ADD THIS ###
  // set IPV6_V6ONLY=0 so that the server uses dualstack sockets
  // i.e., we will get both IPv6 and IPv4-mapped IPv6 connections on the same socket
  // (ignore errors)
  Zero := 0;
  setsockopt(Socket, IPPROTO_IPV6, {IPV6_V6ONLY}27, @Zero, SizeOf(Zero));
  // ### END ADD ###

  // Set TCP buffer sizes
  if FTcpSendBuffer > 0 then begin
    if setsockopt(Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, @FTcpSendBuffer, SizeOf(FTcpSendBuffer)) = SOCKET_ERROR then begin
      ErrnoCopy := WSAGetLastError;
      LogDelegate(Format('TServerSocket.Listen() setsockopt() SO_SNDBUF %s', [SysErrorMessage(ErrnoCopy)]));
      raise TTransportExceptionNotOpen.Create(Format('Could not set SO_SNDBUF: %s', [SysErrorMessage(ErrnoCopy)]));
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Great! Would it be possible to send a pull request? I can't just take the code and commit it myself, for legal reasons. But I can review and merge a pull request. - https://github.com/apache/thrift